# How do I use RegEx to extract something ending in zipcode

Tags: regex

If I have some text in the format 
Mail To - {what i want to extract) `98012-2345`
what do I do?
I dont seem to be able to get the regex to get that the termination will be

```
ddddd-dddd
```

So far I have tried a pattern of `MAIL TO (.*) [ddddd]-[dddd]`

This is using .Net 4.6.

Comment: ok so wierd I have it working with this 
"MAIL TO - (.*?) ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])"

I guess I need to stop being a newbie :-)

Answer (score 1):

The ZIP code regex you want looks like this:

```
\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?
```

What you have up there can be collapsed down to simply `[d]-[d]`, and even further to `d-d`, meaning it will match two literal `d` characters separated by a hyphen, which is clearly not what you're after.

In the regex I provided, I've made the second part of the ZIP code optional (as it is in many cases), meaning you'll match both partial (5-digit) and complete (9-digit) ZIP codes. Just be sure to actually validate the ZIP code, as that isn't something I'd recommend doing with a regex.